# Sending information regarding all tabs but listener only working once and displays final tab's URL

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My extension is sending the tab URL's of all tabs in the window when I press a button. For some reason it's only sending one message, only the last tab's URL is received. What I wish to do is create a list of all the URL's of each tab. So for instance if one had two tabs 'google.ca' and 'bing.ca' I would be able to gather this information and ultimately list both URL's. At the moment I am only getting back one URL though, which in this example would be bing.ca.

**background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(buttonClicked)

function buttonClicked(){
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow:true},function(tabs){   //currentWindow:true ensures all tabs   
        tabs.forEach(function(tab){
         chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id,tab.url);
       });
    });
}
```

**sketch.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(gotMessage);

var messagesReceived = 0;   //even tracking how many messages are received manually and this increments 
                            //only once 

function gotMessage(message,sender,sendResponse){
    console.log("\n");
    console.log(message);
    messagesReceived += 1;
    console.log(messagesReceived);
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you want so I'll describe what actually happens. Each tab has its own instance of the content script so your code sends exactly one message to each tab and that one message is received by the respective content script instance. Note, you don't need messaging for this: each content script can simply use `location.href` to get the URL of its own tab.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity what I'm trying to do is create a list of all the URL's of each tab. So for instance if one had two tabs 'google.ca' and 'bing.ca' I would be able to gather this information and ultimately list both URL's. At the moment I am only getting back one URL though, which in this example would be bing.ca.

Comment: I still don't understand the final goal and my explanation about content script instances seems not to be getting across to you: what happens now is correct because this is how extensions work. If you want to send a list of all tabs to each tab's content script then you should send the entire `tabs` array or just a list of URLs like `tabs.map(t => t.url)`.

Comment: And to clarify, the tabs you want are in the same window? as defined here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#current-window . I ask, because the comment in your code states that setting currentWindow: true ensures all tabs, but that's not entirely true. It gets you only the tabs in the current window.

Comment: Yes all the tabs are in the same window which is why I'm confused. From my understanding shouldn't it send a message conveying the URL of each tab, since "tabs.forEach(function(tab){" would iterate through each tab in the window