# Sending multiple message queries but listener only picks up one message

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to send the URL's of every tab in a window from background.js to another file (sketch.js). My background.js is sending every URL but my other files listener only picks up one URL (the current tab). In the end I want to be able to open a new tab and see a list of all the current open tabs and their URL's.

**background.js:**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(buttonClicked)

function buttonClicked(){
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow:true},function(tabs){     
        tabs.forEach(function(tab){
         chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id,tab.title);
         console.log(tab.title)
       });
    });
}
```

**sketch.js:**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(gotMessage);

var messagesReceived = 0;

function gotMessage(message,sender,sendResponse){
    console.log("\n");
    console.log(message);
    messagesReceived += 1;
    console.log(messagesReceived);
}
```

Comment: As I've [already explained](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59558219) a month ago: what happens now is correct because this is how extensions work. Each tab has its own instance of the content script so your code sends exactly one message to each tab and that one message is received by the respective content script instance. Note, you don't need messaging for this: each content script can simply use location.href to get the URL of its own tab. If you want to send a list of all tabs to each tab's content script then you should send the entire array or just a list of URLs like `tabs.map(t => t.url)`

Comment: I appreciate your explanation and understand what you mean now. Would a possible solution be to push all these URL's into an array and send it to sketch.js?

Comment: Sounds exactly like what I suggested so yes.

Comment: Solved my issue thank you for your persistence / detailed explanation it really did help out.